# looping just once why?

Tags: php, foreach

Suppose i have the following data.

Now i am trying to group all the values of each group in one array.

Suppose $temp_array contaib all of the results that i have.
Now i am trying to group all the data based on the id-

So i am trying to do this ---

```
array(
values (
id -225
name1= hello
name2= 45
name3= burger
,
id -225
name1= bacon
name2= cheese))
```

so i have tried like so---

```
$count=count($temp_array); // $temp_array contains all results
foreach ($temp_array as $key => $var) {

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($count); ++$j) {
        $data = array();
        $data['id'] = $var[$j]['id'];
        $data['name'] = $var[$j]['name'];
        }}
```

but the problem is it is only looping one time, means the `[0]` value. 
so i get the result like so ---

```
    array(
    values (
    id -225
    name1= hello
    name2= 0
    name3= 0
    ,
    id -225
    name1= bacon
    name2= 0
...))
```

my results ---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array // group number 0
        (
            [0] => Array
                ([id] => 225
                [name] => hello
            )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 225
                    name] => ham
                        )

            [2] => Array
                (
                [id] => 225
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 225
                    name] => burger
                  )
    [1] => Array // group number 1
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 45
                    name] => bacon
                  )
                  [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 45
                    name] => cheese
                        )
```

can someone try to help me to fix this problem

Comment: What is $count?? @Christofer : I think you have to use $var

Comment: where are you setting the `$count` ? Is it misstyping or defined before somewhere else?

Comment: too many `count` statements ! You do not need the `count` statement in the loop `for ($j = 0; $j < count($count); ++$j) {` as you have already declared the variable `$count`

Comment: i have update my question, please have a look, thanks

Comment: Why do you need a for loop inside foreach in this case??

Comment: i see no logical match between your input and your required output, where is the id 45 in your input??

Comment: all i need to sto group all the data which have the same id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$count 's value is an integer so you are apllying an extra count() function

replace the

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($count); ++$j) {
```

with

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; ++$j) {
```

Also you can try like this:

```
 $data = array();
 foreach($tempArrray as $row) {
     $data[$row['id']][] = $row;
 }
```

Comment: sorry may be u did not see this -Array
`(
    [0] => Array 
        (
            [0]`

Comment: `count()` function Returns the number of elements so `$count` is an integer right? In the loop you are aplying 2nd time `count()` function to an integer thats why i want to say

Comment: that's true but that is not solving my problem, sorry

Comment: you are simply doing like this : `$a = 5;
echo count($a); // prints 1`

Comment: @ChristoferHansen i updated my answer pls consider is an idea not the last reviewed code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`$count` is an integer.

If you `count($count)`, it will count string length of `$count` which is **1**.

`count()` function works differently for different data types.

If you pass any integer value to it, it will automatically type cast it to string and will count length.

- For strings, it counts number of characters in it.
- For Arrays, it counts number of elements in it.

In your case, you were getting string length (which is 1) instead of array elements count.

**Change**

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($count); ++$j) {
```

**To**

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; ++$j) {
```

Answer (score -1):

As its inside of an foreach you should concanate your output: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
$count=count($temp_array); // $temp_array contains all results
$data = '';
foreach ($temp_array as $key => $var) {

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($count); ++$j) {
        $data .= array();
        $data['id'] .= $var[$j]['id'];
        $data['name'] .= $var[$j]['name'];
        }}

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your array is incorrect. Your output is this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array // group number 0
    (
        [0] => Array
            ([id] => 225
            [name] => hello
        )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 225
                name] => ham
                    )

        [2] => Array
            (
            [id] => 225
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 225
                name] => burger
              ) // you need to close this array [0] with another ),
[1] => Array // group number 1
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 45
                name] => bacon
              )
              [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 45
                name] => cheese
```

i've edited the array and tested it with the code you've made and it worked fine. Build it like this:

```
$array = Array
(
'0' => Array // group number 0
(
    '0' => Array
    ('id' => 225,
        'name' => 'hello'
    ),

    '1' => Array
    (
        'id' => 225,
        'name' => 'ham'
    ),

    '2' => Array
    (
        'id' => 225
    ),

    '3' => Array
    (
        'id' => 225,
        'name' => 'burger'
    )),
    '1' => Array // group number 1
    (
        '0' => Array
        ('id' => 222,
            'name' => 'test'
        ),

        '1' => Array
        (
            'id' => 225,
            'name' => 'ham'
        ),

        '2' => Array
        (
            'id' => 225
        )));
```

and also what they have mentioned before

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $count; ++$j) {
    $data = array();
    $data['id'] = $var[$j]['id'];
    $data['name'] = $var[$j]['name'];

    print_r($data);
}}
```